# How to pass the colored values of DataGridView to ListBox?

Tags: c#

How can I pass the value of the colored cells (DGV1 = DataGridView1)) to the ListBox? In the above example of the illustration, only one colored cell is transferred to the ListBox. But how can I transfer the value of all colored cells from the DataGridView to the ListBox (see DGV2)?
Thank you all for your help!

```
var YellowCell = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(row => new
{
    nameCol = row.Cells[row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().First(cell => cell.OwningColumn.HeaderText == "XX").ColumnIndex].Value,
    
    coloredCells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().First(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow).Value,
}).ToList();

YellowCell.ForEach(s => listBox1.Items.Add($"{s.nameCol} : { s.coloredCells}"));
```

[image]

Comment: Rather than using `First` why don't you use `Where(c => c.Style.BackColor ==Color.Yellow)`.

Comment: Thanks for the note WSC, but it doesn't work that way...

Comment: After you change it to Where as suggested by @WSC, you must change your ForEach to loop through each item of s.ColoredCells too

Comment: I dont really know, Martheen. How to modify the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I would loop through your DataGridView rows and within that loop through the cells, then add the cell value to a collection when they match the criteria you've set out (in this case `BackColor == Color.Yellow`).

For example:

```cs
var yellowCellValues = new List<string>(); //the type should be whatever is in your dgv

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
        {
            yellowCellValues.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

You probably could do it in a LINQ statement, but if you're not familiar with LINQ I think the above `foreach` is much more intuitive and will allow you to easily use the same pattern for other things.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your efforts, WSC!  Your code can be executed! But I am specifically interested in whether the task could be solved with LINQ.

Comment: In that case, you should add that to your question.

Comment: @Marcel16 SelectMany then

Comment: Thanks Martheen. I will keep trying until i solve this problem...